# OpsWorks terminate instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

Does anyone know, in instances timebased, how to terminate rather than stop every time she goes to stop?

I'm trying to terminate by recipe, but it can not proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough to use the [Opsworks API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/OpsWorks/Client.html) to do this directly;

```ruby
require 'aws-sdk-core'
opsworks = Aws::OpsWorks::Client.new region: 'us-east-1'
opsworks.stop_instance(instance_id: instance_id)

begin
  sleep 5
end until(opsworks.describe_instances(instance_ids: [instance_id]).
            instances.first.status == 'stopped')

opsworks.delete_instance(instance_id: instance_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could terminate by disabling the instance termination status and deleting it directly from the EC2 api